# pm2 on docker stucks at getMonitorData

Tags: docker, docker-compose, pm2

I am trying to deploy my application which consists of several microservices, each are in different docker containers. One of them (main-service as seen below) hangs at pm2:client Calling daemon method `Calling daemon method pm2:getMonitorData on rpc socket:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock` message and keeps printing same message. I tried to read the pm2 source code, read the documentation and looked everywhere on the internet but couldn't find a solution. Here is the debug log.

```
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.482Z axon:sock attempting reconnect
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.482Z axon:sock closing
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.482Z axon:sock closing 0 connections
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.482Z pm2:client Daemon not launched
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.482Z axon:sock connect attempt null:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49: PM2 log: Launching in no daemon mode
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.596Z axon:sock bind null:/root/.pm2/pub.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.597Z axon:sock bind null:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.602Z interactor:client Interaction file does not exists
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.602Z interactor:client Secret key is not defined in configuration { version_management: { active: true },
main-service_1    |   public_key: undefined,
main-service_1    |   secret_key: undefined,
main-service_1    |   machine_name: '572eeba2cd52',
main-service_1    |   pm2_version: '3.2.2',
main-service_1    |   reverse_interact: true,
main-service_1    |   info_node: 'https://root.keymetrics.io',
main-service_1    |   agent_transport_websocket: 'false',
main-service_1    |   agent_transport_axon: 'true' }
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z pm2:client Launching RPC client on socket file /root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z axon:sock connect attempt null:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z axon:sock attempting reconnect
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z axon:sock closing
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z axon:sock closing 0 connections
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z interactor:client Interactor Daemon not launched
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z axon:sock connect attempt null:/root/.pm2/interactor.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z axon:sock attempting reconnect
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z axon:sock closing
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.604Z axon:sock closing 0 connections
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.605Z interactor:client Interactor Daemon not launched
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.605Z axon:sock connect attempt null:/root/.pm2/interactor.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.605Z axon:sock error ENOENT
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.605Z axon:sock ignored ENOENT
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.605Z axon:sock error ENOENT
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.605Z axon:sock ignored ENOENT
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.605Z axon:sock error ENOENT
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.605Z axon:sock ignored ENOENT
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.606Z axon:sock accept /root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.607Z axon:sock add socket 0
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.608Z axon:sock connect
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.608Z axon:sock add socket 0
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.608Z axon:queue flush 0 messages
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.608Z pm2:client RPC Connected to Daemon
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.614Z axon:sock connect attempt null:/root/.pm2/pub.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.614Z axon:sock accept /root/.pm2/pub.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.614Z axon:sock add socket 0
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.614Z axon:sock connect
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.614Z axon:sock add socket 0
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.615Z axon:sub subscribe to "log:*"
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.615Z pm2:cli Resolved filepath /ecosystem.config.js
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.639Z pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:getMonitorData on rpc socket:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.662Z pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:prepare on rpc socket:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49: PM2 log: App [API:0] starting in -fork mode-
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.665Z pm2:fork_mode stds: {"out":"/root/.pm2/logs/API-out-0.log","err":"/root/.pm2/logs/API-error-0.log"}
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49: PM2 log: App [API:0] online
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.677Z pm2:god Error vizion::analyze() for given folder: /
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:49.678Z pm2:god Error vizion::analyze() for given folder: /
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:55.680Z pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:getMonitorData on rpc socket:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:57.689Z pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:getMonitorData on rpc socket:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:03:59.693Z pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:getMonitorData on rpc socket:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock
main-service_1    | 2018-12-07T18:04:01.697Z pm2:client Calling daemon method pm2:getMonitorData on rpc socket:/root/.pm2/rpc.sock
```

Here is my Dockerfile for mainService

```
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-jessie
COPY ./ ./
ENV MONGO_URL=http://localhost:3007/slickpoll_polls
ENV DEBUG=*
EXPOSE 3002
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -D ts-node
RUN npm install -D typescript
RUN pm2 install typescript
CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "start", "ecosystem.config.js" ]
```

And here is my ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'API',
    script: 'app.ts',

    // Options reference: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/
    instances: 1,
    autorestart: true,
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    }
  }]
};
```

And here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    users-database:
        build: ./usersDatabase
        volumes:
            - ~/dbs/usersDatabase:/data/db
        ports:
            - 27017:3006
        networks: 
            - usersdb
    polls-database:
        build: ./pollsDatabase
        volumes:
            - ~/dbs/pollsDatabase:/data/db
        ports:
            - 27017:3007
        networks: 
            - pollsdb
    users-service:
        build: ./usersService
        ports:
            - 3004:3004
        networks: 
            - users
            - usersdb
        depends_on:
            - users-database
    poll-service:
        build: ./pollService
        ports:
            - 3003:3003
        depends_on: 
            - polls-database
        networks: 
            - pollsdb
            - api
    main-service:
        build: ./mainService
        ports:
            - 3002:3002
        networks: 
            - pollsdb
            - users
            - api
        depends_on:
            - users-database
            - users-service
            - polls-database

networks:
    users:
        driver: overlay
        internal: true
    usersdb:
        driver: overlay
        internal: true
    pollsdb:
        driver: overlay
        internal: true
    api:
```

I spent almost whole day on fixing this but couldn't succeed. I don't have much hope to solve it anymore. I hope you can find a solution.

Comment: There are a couple of log files mentioned in your error trace; if you `docker exec` into the container, do they say anything interesting?  (Your MongoDB URL is almost definitely wrong, but it’s hard to say whether that does or doesn’t cause the problem you’re seeing.)

Comment: @DavidMaze no, there are no interesting indicators in container's bash.